# How to log into my app if facebook native app is logged in

Tags: android, facebook, facebook-graph-api

I am using Facebook SDK for login purpose. But what I want is, when a user is logged in the facebook native app, I want them to redirect to my main activity without asking log in information (facebook login dialog). Also whenever a user is not logged into the facebook app, I want to display the facebook login options. I am using the following code but I am unable to make use of it. I tried single sign in but I failed to integrate the functionality, please help me in finding the solution.

My code is as follows:

```
loginButton = (LoginButton) findViewById(R.id.login_button);
        loginButton.setLoginBehavior(SessionLoginBehavior.SUPPRESS_SSO);
        loginButton.setPublishPermissions(PERMISSIONS);
        loginButton.setUserInfoChangedCallback(new LoginButton.UserInfoChangedCallback() {
            @Override
            public void onUserInfoFetched(GraphUser user) {
                LoginActivity.this.user = user;

                userSignUp();
            }
        });

private void userSignUp(){

        if(MyApplication.getInstance().isOnline(LoginActivity.this)){
            if(user != null){

                //displayProgress();
                JSONObject requestObj = new JSONObject();
                JSONObject fbObj = new JSONObject();
                JSONObject userObj = new JSONObject();

                try {
                    System.out.println("fbid"+user.getId());
                    common.savePref(LoginActivity.this,Constants.FaceBookID, user.getId());
                    common.savePref(LoginActivity.this,Constants.UserName, user.getFirstName()+ " "+ user.getLastName());
                    common.savePref(LoginActivity.this,Constants.FirstName, user.getFirstName());
                    common.savePref(LoginActivity.this,Constants.LastName, user.getLastName());
                    fbObj.put("id", user.getId());
                    fbObj.put("userName", user.getFirstName()+ " "+ user.getLastName());
                    fbObj.put("firstName", user.getFirstName());
                    fbObj.put("lastName", user.getLastName());
                //  fbObj.put("deviceId", common.getDeviceId(LoginActivity.this));
                    userObj.put("deviceId", getRegistrationId(context));
                    userObj.put("deviceType", "android");
                    requestObj.put("facebook", fbObj);
                    requestObj.put("user", userObj);
                } catch (JSONException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }

                JsonObjectRequest jsonObjReq = new JsonObjectRequest(Method.POST,
                        WebService.fbSignUpUrl(), requestObj,
                        new Listener<JSONObject>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onResponse(JSONObject response) {
                        Log.d(TAG, response.toString());
                        try {
                            System.out.println("response::::"+response);
                            common.savePref(LoginActivity.this, Constants.UserAliasName, response.getString(Constants.UserAliasName));
                            common.savePref(LoginActivity.this, Constants.userId, response.getString(Constants.userId));    
                            Intent intent = new Intent(LoginActivity.this,MainActivity.class);
                            LoginActivity.this.startActivity(intent);
                            LoginActivity.this.finish();
                        } catch (JSONException e) {
                            e.printStackTrace();
                        }
                    }
                }, new ErrorListener() {

                    @Override
                    public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                        VolleyLog.d(TAG, "Error: " + error.getMessage());
                        // hide the progress dialog
                        //pDialog.hide();
                    }
                });
                // Adding request to request queue
                MyApplication.getInstance().addToRequestQueue(jsonObjReq, tag_json_obj);
                //makeJsonArrayRequest();
            }
        }
        else{
            Common.displayAlertDialog(this, getString(R.string.offline));
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Try checking session object.

```html
Session mFacebookSession = Session.getActiveSession();
if (mFacebookSession == null)) 
{
  //session is null
}else if(mFacebookSession.isClosed())
{
  //session is closed
}else if(mFacebookSession.isOpened())
{
  //session is opened
}
```

Comment: This is not a complete code. I believe you have complete knowledge regarding FB sdk. You need to put this where you want to check.